# extracting the last two digits of a year in java from a string

Tags: java

I have a string variable in which date is stored as shown below

```
newDateString = formatter.format(oldDate);
```

so the date inside newDateString variable is stored in format is

```
20/06/0012
```

now i want to extract the last two digit and stored in a seprate strig variable so it will be in the form

```
String xx=newDateString.split("00/")[2];
```

now please advise this is not bringing the correct result how to achieve the correct result i want that xx should contain the value 12 please advise how to achieve this

Answer (score 5):

You can use substring like this:

```
String last2Digit=  newDateString.substring(newDateString.length()-2);
```

Answer (score 4):

> I want to extract the last two digit and stored in a separate string variable

This is just

```
String last = s.substring(s.length() - 2);
```

> this is not bringing the correct result

This is because `"00/"` doesn't appear in your string. Even if you correct this, it would only appear once.

```
String xx = newDateString.split("/00")[1];
```

Note: this will only work for years `0001` to `0099` and I suspect that's not very useful.